# PowerShell: Struggling to add multiple users to M365 Group from CSV

Tags: powershell

This is a really annoying problem that is now driving me nuts! I'm hoping it's something that i've just missed but I can't figure it out or google it out just yet so here goes:

I have a CSV containing data that i'm using to provision 365 groups and populate the members - pretty straightforward. Everything works apart from when we get to adding members. For some reason despite the userPrincipalNames being in the correct format as per documentation and numerous articles online ("user.1@domain","user.2@domain","user.3@domain") it only recognises them as a single object that it can't locate in AD. However, when I provide a variable within the script using the same format it works!

This is an example of what i'm trying that isn't working:

[CSV Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpz6.png)

Script Example:

```
$CSVimport = import-csv "c:\MyData.csv"

foreach ($Row in $CSVimport){
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Row.DisplayName -LinkType "Members" -Links $Row.GroupMembers
}
```

The error I receive is:

Couldn't find object ""user.1@domain","user.2@domain","user.3@domain"". Please make sure that it was spelled correctly or specify a different object.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (My-Group-Name:UnifiedGroupIdParameter) [Add-UnifiedGroupLinks], ADNoSuchObjectException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=DB7PR04MB5454,RequestId=be97bad9-ad7e-4930-bcad-63eb4899abcc,TimeStamp=06/01/2023 15:21:58] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADNoSuchObjectException] A66FD2D7,Microsoft.Excha
nge.Management.RecipientTasks.AddUnifiedGroupLinks
+ PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

The script that works:

Script Example:

```
$CSVimport = import-csv "c:\MyData.csv"
$Members = "user.1@domain","user.2@domain","user.3@domain"

foreach ($Row in $CSVimport){
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Row.DisplayName -LinkType "Members" -Links $Members
}
```

I need the CSV method to work as i'm doing this on bulk, i've also tried to workaround this by using various split and replace methods but my PS knowledge is limited when coming to strange issues like this, here's hoping someone knows where i'm going wrong!

Comment: Judging from the error message you show, the Group members field is enclosed in quotes, in addition to each member being enclosed in quotes.  That may be impossible for Add-UnifiedGroupLinks to parse.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, it appears that `add-unifiedgrouplinks` is unable to handle or parse the information from the CSV horizontally/in a single cell. I've had to abandon looking for a tidy solution and am using a `foreach` loop to export the group members into separate CSV files so they can be looped vertically as [aamdevsecops](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20846337/aamdevsecops) originally suggested in a comment as this was the only workable solution in the end.

Comment: Add-Member always works for me : $Row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Column_Name -NotePropertyValue Column_Value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$Members = $Row.GroupMembers -split ','` to parse GroupMembers (from your CSV file) into an array of strings and define:

```
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Row.DisplayName -LinkType "Members" -Links $Members
```

Something like:

```
$CSVimport = import-csv "c:\MyData.csv"

foreach ($Row in $CSVimport){
    $Members = $Row.GroupMembers -split ','
    Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Row.DisplayName -LinkType "Members" -Links $Members
}
```

Comment: Hi aamdevsecops,

Thanks for the response! I think part of the issue here is that my values in the CSV file are comma separated because using your method above only adds the first user in the list. 

I have tried the below method where I changed the comma's in the CSV file to / and then did the below just to get them into that format that I thought may be parsing them (but as I said my knowledge isn't great) this is what else i've tried:

Comment: `foreach ($Row in $CSVimport) {
    $Members = $Row.GroupMembers.Replace('/',',')
    [array]$Members1 = '"'+$Members
    [string]$FinalMembers = $null
    $FinalMembers = $Members1 -join ","
    $FinalMembers
    Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Row.DisplayName -LinkType "Members" -Links $FinalMembers
}`

Unfortunately that still throws the same error despite correctly pulling in all the users and displaying them in that format.

Comment: have you tried reformatting your GroupMembers into vertical rows rather than one field? Hope you get it sorted out!

Comment: I haven't but that's only because i'm trying to do this on bulk where i've exported information from around 50 different groups each into a row, so was really hoping to make this work with the data of a single column. I may have to think a bit more outside the box on this one though! or go for a different solution to get these members added - thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here.  Have you tried Select Object with the -expand option?  This might be able to convert the format you have into an ungrouped format.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the contents of the CSV file using the code block tool in the stackoverflow dialog box.  Knowing exactly where the double quotes and the commas are in the csv file viewed as text is crucial to figuring out what the M365 tool can't parse.

Comment: Hi @WalterMitty, I did actually try using the -expand option yes but it didn't want to play ball. I did put an example of the CSV in my OP, link to the image: [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpz6.png but as requested here's a codeblock:
`DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress,Description,GroupMembers
My-GroupName,My-Group-Name@domain,My Group,"User.1@domain","User.2@domain","User.3@domain"`